# Svelte Typescript - exctracting props types

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-component

Problem: I want to create a function that takes a component as first argument and his props as second in a generic way

```js
   import FileUpload from "./FileUpload.svelte";

  function openModal(component: typeof FileUpload, componentProps: ConstructorParameters<typeof FileUpload>['0']['props']) {
    /** Do stuff*/
  }

  openModal(FileUpload, { xD: true })
```

This works, it's just not generic, I cant understand what to use in the generic types

I've tried `T extends SvelteComponent, T extends Svelte2TsxComponent`

Answer (score 2):

I kind of solved it

Im not sure what should I place instead of those "any, any", but it seems to work anyways, any bonus explanation would be appreciated, thanks :D

```js
function openModal<T extends SvelteComponentConstructor<any, any>>(component: T, componentProps: ConstructorParameters<T>['0']['props']) {
    /** Do stuff*/
  }
```

PS: I'm waiting to give the "correct answer" in case someone finds a better solution, as I dont really like this one